# Vert.x Spring Stream Video steps or Source code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm using Spring WebFlux. Here is My Service :

```
@Service
public class VideoStreamimpl implements IVideoStream {
    private static final String FORMAT="classpath:videos/%s.mp4";

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Override
    public Mono<Resource> getVideo(String title){
        return Mono.fromSupplier(
                ()->resourceLoader.getResource(
                        String.format(FORMAT,title)
                )
        );
    }
}
```

here's my controller :

```
@RestController
public class VideoStreamController {
    @Autowired
    private IVideoStream iVideoStreamimpl;
    @GetMapping(value = "videos/{title}" , produces = "video/mp4")
    public Mono<Resource> ShowSingleVide(@PathVariable String title , @RequestHeader("Range")  String Range){
        System.out.println("Range in Bytes() : "+Range);
        return   iVideoStreamimpl.getVideo(title);
    }
}
```

I found that, the `vert x` is better than `Spring WebFlux` so I want to use `Vert.X` in my project .

How to use `Vert.x` in spring to get Video Stream?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to use Vert.x in spring to get Video Stream

Comment: What *is better* means exactly? Have you tried something that did not work out?

Comment: no i don't know how to do it